# Validación si es un entero, String o booleano de una Jlista el primer elemento y pasarlo a una lista dependiendo su valor. En Java NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Hola  amigos buenas noche, lo que pasa es que necesito crear un programa con Jframe el cual Tenga cuatro listas(ListaPrincipal, ListaCadenas, ListaEnteros, ListaBooleanos). La primera lista la llenare con elementos desde un Jtext ya sean cadenas, números o booleanos, con el botón eliminar se quitara el primer elemento de la lista y se validara dependiendo su valor ya se enteros, cadenas o booleanos y se insertara en la Lista correspondiente.

Alguien podría ayudarme, de antemano se los agradezco por su tiempo.

```
public dos() {
    initComponents();
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    ModeloListaPrimera = new DefaultListModel();
    JLPrimera.setModel(ModeloListaPrimera);
    ModeloListaCadena = new DefaultListModel();
    JLCadena.setModel(ModeloListaCadena);
    ModeloListaEntero = new DefaultListModel();
    JLEntero.setModel(ModeloListaEntero);
    ModeloLsitaBoleano = new DefaultListModel();
    JLBoleanos.setModel(ModeloLsitaBoleano);

}
```

///Inicia mi método del botón;

private void PasarActionPerformed (java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

```
    if (ModeloListaPrimera.size() > 0) {
        ModeloListaPrimera.getElementAt(filas);
            String v = ModeloListaPrimera.toString();
            for (int i = 0; i < v.length(); i++) {
                if (Character.isDigit(v.charAt(i))) {
                    ModeloListaEntero.addElement(v);
                   } else {
                    if (Character.isBmpCodePoint(i)) {
                        ModeloLsitaBoleano.addElement(v);
                    } else{
                        ModeloListaCadena.addElement(v);
                    }
                }

        }
            ModeloListaPrimera.remove(filas);


    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No existe elementos");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

espero ayudarte. Tome en cuenta que tomaras los valores del JTextField como cadenas y en base a listaPrincipal teniendo cada cadena a convertir. He aquí el código.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class StackOverFlow1 {

    ArrayList<Object> listaPrincipal = new ArrayList<Object>();

    ArrayList<Boolean> listaBooleanos = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
    ArrayList<Integer> listaNumeros = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<String> listaCadenas = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // prueba de funcionamiento
        StackOverFlow1 stof = new StackOverFlow1();
        String valores[] = {"true", "1", "asdasdasd", "false", "12000"};
        for (int i=0; i<valores.length; stof.listaPrincipal.add(valores[i]),i++);

        // una vez agregado a la lista principal cada uno como cadenas tomadas del 
        // objeto.getText() siendo objeto el JTextField
        stof.obtenerValoresListaPrincipal();

        stof.mostrarLista(stof.listaBooleanos);
        stof.mostrarLista(stof.listaCadenas);
        stof.mostrarLista(stof.listaNumeros);

    }

    public void mostrarLista(ArrayList lista) {
        // mostrar la lista
        for (int i=0; i<lista.size(); i++)
            System.out.println(lista.get(i).toString());
    }

    public boolean esNumeroEntero(String cadena) {
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(cadena);
        } catch(NumberFormatException i) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;    
    }

    public void obtenerValoresListaPrincipal() {
        for (Object objeto: listaPrincipal) {
                // Booleanos
                if (objeto.equals("true"))
                    listaBooleanos.add(true);
                else if(objeto.equals("false"))
                    listaBooleanos.add(false);
                else if (esNumeroEntero(objeto.toString()))
                    listaNumeros.add(Integer.parseInt(objeto.toString()));
                else
                    listaCadenas.add(objeto.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Guardas en una variable String cadena, el valor a validar de la cadena principal y lo pasas por este metodo;

```
public void validar(String cadena){
   if(esBoolean(cadena){
    boolean valor= Boolean.parseBoolean(cadena);  
    //lo metes en la lista de booleans
   }else if(esEntero(cadena)){
    int valorNum = Integer.parseInt(cadena);
     // lo metes en la lista de enteros
   }else
     //lo metes en la lista de cadenas
 }



private boolean esBoolean(String cadena){
 return cadena.equals(false)||cadena.equals(true);
}

private boolean esEntero(String cadena){
   boolean noCorte= true;
   for(int i=0;i<cadena.length()&&noCorte;i++){
     if(i==0&&cadena.charAt(i)=='-')
         noCorte=true;
     else  
         noCorte = esNum(cadena.charAt(i));
 }
  return noCorte;
}
private boolean esNum(char caracter){
  boolean resultado=false;
    switch(caracter) {
    case '1': resultado=true;;
       break;
    case '2': resultado=true;;
       break;
    case '3': resultado=true;;
       break;
    case '4': resultado=true;;
       break;
    case '5': resultado=true;;
       break;
    case '6': resultado=true;;
       break;
    case '7': resultado=true;;
       break;
    case '8': resultado=true;;
       break;
    case '9': resultado=true;;
       break;
    case '0': resultado=true;;
       break;


    }
    return resultado;
}
```